# Laravel 5.4/Blade not showing a variable that is an empty string with a space: " "

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This is a weird question, as it feels so simple, but alas it has me stuck. I have a variable: `$customer->PhoneWork` that is currently empty, returning `" "`. In the Blade template, I want to conditionally render it only if it is not empty:

```
    @unless (empty($customer->PhoneWork))
      Work: {{ $customer->PhoneWork }}
    @endunless
```

The problem is, though it seems like it would be empty right now, `empty($customer->PhoneWork)` is false. I also tried `is_null()` and `!isset()` and all are experiencing the same issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you have __space__ in a value - it is __not__ empty.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Determine whether a variable is empty

So if the variable is `empty` it will return `true` and if it is not, it will return `false`.

As a result, you need to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the value and reverse the check:

```
@if (!empty(trim($customer->PhoneWork))
```

This check is now saying: *If `$customer->PhoneWork` (trimmed) is NOT empty*

Comment: That still returns false. There's `ctype_space()`, but I shouldn't rely on it always being a white space issue.

Comment: The value is currently a string with one space: `" "` The logic of `!empty(trim($customer->PhoneWork))` makes sense, but it's not executing properly in the blade template. It's still returning false, when the current goal is to establish that it's true for the `@unless`.

Comment: If you continue to use unless, you'll need to get rid of the `!` (not).

Comment: Yep! `!empty(trim($customer->PhoneHome))` returns true and that currently has a phone number string. It then doesn't show :/

Comment: But of course! It just needs to be `empty(trim($customer->PhoneWork))`. Then it's checking if `trim($customer->PhoneWork)` is empty. That is true.

Comment: @MattLarson use `@if` instead of `@unless` with the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to perform an action if the string contains empty characters. so...

function `empty($var)` is equal to `!isset($var) || $var == false`.

You may need to use `ctype_space($str)`

Comment: OP has mentioned that they don't want to rely on `ctype_space`.

Answer (score 0):

`empty(trim($customer->PhoneWork))` does the trick! It checks if the trimmed string is empty.